# WCF DataContracts - How can I use a single DataContract with complex object for both WCF SOAP and REST services?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap, datacontract

I have a frustrating issue that I have been trying too overcome but can't seem to figure out.

I have services that I am exposing over both SOAP and REST endpoints in WCF. To avoid duplicate object code, I want to reuse the contract objects between the two services.FYI,I am using two separate interfaces because there are many API calls that I have that are different between the two endpoints. A simple example of these services is shown below:

```
/*REST Implementation*/
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
     [OperationContract]
     [WebInvoke]
     TestResponse Test(TestRequest request);

     [OperationContract]
     [WebGet]
     int GetTest(int testId);

}

/*SOAP Implementation*/
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService
{
     [OperationContract]
     [WebInvoke]
     TestResponse Test(TestRequest request);

     [OperationContract]
     [WebInvoke]
     int GetTest(GetTestRequest request);
}

[DataContract(Namespace="http://www.mysite.com/Test")]
public class TestRequest
{
     [DataMember]
     public int ID {get;set;}

     [DataMember]
     public InnerTestRequest InnerTestRequest {get;set;}
}

[DataContract(Namespace="http://www.mysite.com/Test")]
public class InnerTestRequest
{
     [DataMember]
     public int ID {get;set;}
}
```

**THE PROBLEM** The problem I am running into is I would like the contract payload for both of the endpoints to use the same XML structure (within the SOAP envelope for the SOAP endpoint).

For example, making a call to the **Test(TestRequest request)** on the REST endpoint, I would like to  send the following XML:

```
 <TestRequest xmlns="http://www.mysite.com/Test">
     <InnerTestRequest>
         <ID>2</ID>       
     </InnerTestRequest>
     <ID>4</ID>
</TestRequest>
```

and for the SOAP endpoint, I would expect to be able to send the following:

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <TestRequest xmlns="http://www.mysite.com/Test">
          <InnerTestRequest>
              <ID>2</ID>
          </InnerTestRequest>
          <ID>4</ID>
      </TestRequest>
  </s:Body>
```

I would also like the responses to be in the same format with the same contract payload. I have tried multiple methods to accomplish this including using the [MessageContractAttribute] and specifying namespace, as well as setting the BodyStyle to BodyStyle.Bare, but I am still running into the two following problems:

```
1. The http://www.mysite.com/Test namespace does not trickle down to the members of its class.
2. SOAP requests "wrap" the contract, and it changes the structure of the XML.
```

What is the best way to accomplish this without specifying two separate DataContracts, one for REST and one for SOAP.

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: Interesting.  Have you tried explicitly specifying namespaces on each datamember?

Comment: yes, and it doesn't work :/ I have also searched several references, but have been unsuccessful. I am currently trying the following solution, but it is causing problems with the SOAP endpoint serialization of the contract. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/wcf/thread/dc3344df-f0e9-4cd3-9d5a-81f4cd6de136

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first item: you also need to define the `[OperationContract]` namespace as the same one in the data contracts, this way you have a consistent namespace story.

For the second item, you were in the right track with message contracts. You'll need to use an *unwrapped* message contract if you want to remove the "wrapping" element.

The code below shows how this can be accomplished.

```
public class StackOverflow_15252991
{
    [DataContract(Name = "TestRequest", Namespace = "http://www.mysite.com/Test")]
    public class TestRequest
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public InnerTestRequest InnerTestRequest { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "InnerTestRequest", Namespace = "http://www.mysite.com/Test")]
    public class InnerTestRequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.mysite.com/Test", Name = "TestResponse")]
    public class TestResponse
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.mysite.com/Test")]
    public interface ITestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke]
        TestResponseContract Test(TestRequestContract request);
    }
    [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
    public class TestRequestContract
    {
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public TestRequest TestRequest { get; set; }
    }
    [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
    public class TestResponseContract
    {
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public TestResponse TestResponse { get; set; }
    }
    public class Service : ITestService
    {
        public TestResponseContract Test(TestRequestContract request)
        {
            return new TestResponseContract { TestResponse = new TestResponse { ID = request.TestRequest.ID } };
        }
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "soap");
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITestService), new WebHttpBinding(), "rest").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        var factory = new ChannelFactory<ITestService>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress + "/soap"));
        var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        var input = new TestRequestContract { TestRequest = new TestRequest { InnerTestRequest = new InnerTestRequest { ID = 2 }, ID = 4 } };
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.Test(input).TestResponse.ID);

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        factory = new ChannelFactory<ITestService>(new WebHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress + "/rest"));
        factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.Test(input).TestResponse.ID);

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Now using the inputs from the OP");
        foreach (bool useSoap in new bool[] { true, false })
        {
            WebClient c = new WebClient();
            c.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";
            if (useSoap)
            {
                c.Headers["SOAPAction"] = "http://www.mysite.com/Test/ITestService/Test";
            }

            string uri = useSoap ?
                baseAddress + "/soap" :
                baseAddress + "/rest/Test";

            Console.WriteLine("Request to {0}", uri);

            string body = @"<TestRequest xmlns=""http://www.mysite.com/Test"">
                                <InnerTestRequest>
                                    <ID>2</ID>       
                                </InnerTestRequest>
                                <ID>4</ID>
                            </TestRequest>";
            if (useSoap)
            {
                body = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Body>" +
                    body +
                    "</s:Body></s:Envelope>";
            }

            Console.WriteLine(c.UploadString(uri, body));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: does this mean I would need to use two separate contracts, one for REST and one for SOAP?

Comment: No. In the example above there's only one contract, used for both. You can also use message contracts in REST endpoints, as shown in this code.

Comment: Carlos...I tried the above solution applied to my project, and I had to switch the IsWrapped=true in order to get it to work? Does this make sense?

Comment: Well, if it worked for you then great :). What I tried to do was to use exactly the XML which you provided - as seen on the `Test` method of my example - and for that I needed an `IsWrapped=false` message contract. But if having a wrapped contract worked in your case, then that's what works for you.

Comment: Well, this is what makes me nervous :) I am more confident in your code than my own, but I am not sure why it would be any different. when I did the IsWrapped = false, the TestResponseContract was not in the repsonse, and the TestReponse was the root XML element :/?

Comment: This is what `IsWrapped` does: if true, then the root of the XML will be the name of the [MC] class (or any `WrapperName` if set on the attribute). If false, then the root will be the (single) `[MessageBodyMember]` element. I used `IsWrapped = false` on the **request**, since that's what you had on your question. On the response since you didn't specify what you needed, I just picked up any value...

Comment: That makes perfect sense, and I'm glad you not only solved my problem, but helped explain how it works. I really appreciate your persistence in helping me understand this!